# condition within the inner join query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

```
function processCCOrder($idCompany){

    $sql = "SELECT oi.order_items_qty * oi.order_items_price AS order_value,si.sales_item_qty * si.price AS invoice_price 
           FROM order_items oi,sales_items si
           where oi.product_idproduct = S.product_idproduct
           SELECT c.customer_name,op.*,s.salesNo,sp.salesperson_name,if(order_value != invoice_price)
           FROM ORDER_PRODUCT OP
           INNER JOIN customer c 
           ON op.customer_idcustomer = c.idcustomer
           INNER JOIN sales s
           ON op.idorder = s.order_idorder
           INNER JOIN sales_person sp
           ON op.idorder = sp.idsales_person
           WHERE oi.idcompany = $idCompany";

    return $sql;
}
```

In above code I try to

- select items_qty * item_price it's new name order_value
- select sales_qty * sale_price it's multiply it's new name invoice_value
- but order_value & invoice value oi.product_idproduct = S.product_idproduct
- next checking if(order_value != invoice_price) it's true
- select the values & do this inner join query

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: #Straberry I can't understand can you explain example, please sir

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only explanation I can provide

Comment: `WHERE some_condition SELECT` would not be valid sql even if you put an AND or OR in there; nor is `Where WHERE`. One of the first steps in debugging any mysql query should be pasting it into MySQL Workbench.